# How to access values of custom objects in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I currently have a custom object

```
public struct GenreData : Decodable {


  public let id : NSNumber?
  public let name : String


  public init?(json: JSON) {

    guard let name : String = "name" <~~ json
      else {return nil}

    self.id = "id" <~~ json
    self.name = name

  }
}
```

I have an array of the custom object and am trying to access the 'id' part of the object so I can plug it in another function :

```
  var genreDataArray: [GenreData] = []
  var posterStringArray: [String] = []
  var posterImageArray: [UIImage] = []

 GenreData.updateAllData(urlExtension:"list", completionHandler: { results in

      guard let results = results else {
        print("There was an error retrieving info")
        return
      }
      self.genreDataArray = results

      for _ in self.genreDataArray {

      if let movieGenreID = self.genreDataArray[0].id {//This is where the ID is needed to access the posters

        print(movieGenreID)

        //Update posters based on genreID
        GenrePosters.updateGenrePoster(genreID: movieGenreID, urlExtension: "movies", completionHandler: {posters in

          //Must iterate through multiple arrays with many containing the same poster strings
          for poster in posters {

            //Check to see if array already has the current poster string, if it does continue, if not append to array
            if self.posterStringArray.contains(poster){
              continue
            } else {
              self.posterStringArray.append(poster)

              //Use the poster string to download the corresponding poster
              self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(poster)",
                { (imageData) //imageData = Image data downloaded from web
                  in
                  if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data){
                    self.posterImageArray.append(image)

                  }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      }
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.genresTableView.reloadData()
      }
    })
```

As of right now all its doing is accessing the first array of the JSON data(there are 19 arrays)and appending every string from that first array to the posterStringArray but instead I need it to go through each array and only append the string if doesn't already exist in the posterStringArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100 percent sure I understood your question, but shouldn't you replace:

```
for _ in self.genreDataArray {

  if let movieGenreID = self.genreDataArray[0].id
```

with

```
for item in self.genreDataArray {

  if let movieGenreID = item.id
```

***update***

to only add one item try adding a break after getting the image:

```
          //Use the poster string to download the corresponding poster
          self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(poster)",
            { (imageData) //imageData = Image data downloaded from web
              in
              if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data){
                self.posterImageArray.append(image)

              }
          })

          break
```

Comment: That helped but it's still appending all the data from the first json array to the posterStringArray where I only want it to append one and then move onto the next array

Comment: I'm getting a crash when trying to access the indexpath.row

Comment: Is there a way to use that same logic to where the strings are being appended to the posterStringsArray before the call for the images are made?

Comment: for poster in posters {

              if self.posterStringArray.contains(poster){
                continue
              } else {
                self.posterStringArray.append(poster)
                print(poster)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do to be honest, but it sounds like multiple questions not one :)

Comment: I'll try and see if I can make it clearer.  I'm accessing different arrays of json data, each array of json data contains numerous strings(posterStrings).  I'm trying to take one string from each json array and append it to the posterStrinsArray, but first checking to see if the posterStringsArray already contains that string, if it does continue to the next item in the array and append it to the posterStrings Array.

Comment: I'm only trying to get one item from each json array and then move onto the json next array

Comment: Ok, then it seems like adding the continue should work, if it doesn't it may be that the problem is in a different part of your code

Comment: maybe the continue is in the wrong spot. It's still adding the whole json array instead of stopping after one

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with this part of the code:   for poster in posters {

              if self.posterStringArray.contains(poster){
                continue
              } else {
                self.posterStringArray.append(poster)
                continue

Comment: oops, sorry, I am tired. it should be break not continue

Comment: I have corrected the answer to say break now, hope it will work :)

Comment: Looks like the break is working, there are some issues but they are unrelated.  Thanks for your help!